# Microsoft access Query IIF statement not returning what i want

Tags: ms-access

I have the below query which is meant to only return lines that are less than the ETA Date.
When applying the criteria below it does return the lines in which the ETA Date is less than today, however it does return the other lines as well and i don't want that.
I just want it to return the lines in which dates are lower than today's date.

```
Overdue: IIf([PO ETA]<=Now(),DateDiff("yyyy",[PO ETA],Now()) & "year(s)" & DateDiff("m",[PO ETA],Now()) & "month(s)" & DateDiff("d",[PO ETA],Now()) & "day(s)")
```

[image]

I have tried to add something for the else statement but i can't seem to figure out what i should add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the *criteria* for that *Overdue* expression:

```
<>""
```

Comment: Oh, such an easy fix. thank you much appreciated.
Could you please explain to me how this works though ?

Comment: You had correctly set up what to filter on, but missed to state how to filter. Now it filters on a zero-length string which is what is returned for 1, 5, 9 records.